# Can an extended use case have a relationship with another actor

Tags: uml, use-case

Is the below valid use case diagram? Can the extended use case be associated with another actor than the base use case?

[image]

Comment: Your extend is the wrong way (I guess): `Check in` will not extend `New patient` but vice versa. However, you should simply not use extend/include since (as in your case) it's used for functional analysis. And that's not the point in UC synthesis.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Yes my bad, It should have been as you suggested. 
Since the Opening of new folder happens during the check-in, I thought it would be good to extend the check-in use case. How would you model that+

Comment: As said: leave it away. UCs are about added value, not about functions and the order they appear in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: yes

Yet you need to be careful. The association to use case shows actor involved in the use case (not necessarily initiating it).

The given example is absolutely fine.

You could also achieve the same result by using UC specialization in case of opening a folder for a new patient rather than existing one.